# Finding Critical Path of Combinational Logic

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, synthesis

I have a combinational circuit and I would like to find its critical path in design compiler. Essentially, I want to find out by how much the combinational logic *will reduce the maximum clock frequency* of the larger sequential design.
For this purpose, I have added registers along the input of the combinational circuit (a simple multiplier in this case) which are clocked on the rising edge of a clock as advised in [How to find the critical path delay of a big combinational block](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61631/how-to-find-the-critical-path-delay-of-a-big-combinational-block). I then run `create_clock clk -period 5 -name clk` and `report_qor` in DC, but I'm getting a Critical Path Length of 0.00 ns. This looks odd. If I move the multiplier directly to the test module, I get a more reasonable-looking Critical Path Length of 4.88 ns however.

```
module my_multiplier(
    output reg [31:0] out,
    input      [15:0] in1, in2,
    input             enable
);

always @(*) begin
   if (enable) begin
         out = in1 * in2;
   end
end

endmodule
```

I've created a separate module to instantiate the multiplier circuit and also clock the inputs to the multiplier:

```
module Test_multiplier_Tcrit(
    output  [31:0] out,
    input   [15:0] in1, in2,
    input          clk, enable
);

reg  [15:0] in1_reg, in2_reg;

my_multiplier my_multiplier(.out(out), .in1(in1_reg), .in2(in2_reg), .enable(enable)); 

always @(posedge clk) begin
   in1_reg <= in1; 
   in2_reg <= in2;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a register on the output as well.  Generally the timing analysis is done register-to-register, so without an output register it may not be able to give you a good answer.

Comment: I've already tried the register to output but get the same result. I used: `always @* out <= out1;` after redeclaring the output port `out` as a register.

Comment: Move the assignment to the output port `out` into a sequential always block to get a register `always@(posedge clk) out <= out1;`

Comment: @damage Doesn't work. Have already tried that.